# Why I am getting this error...if I run this composer require maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

```
 composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

If I run the avobe command I get this error..Is their any alternative...I searched a lot in online but I did not get any solution...I am using the laravel latest version

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update maatwebsite/excel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 7 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
 - Locking composer/semver (3.4.0)
 - Locking ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.17.0)
 - Locking maatwebsite/excel (3.1.51)
 - Locking maennchen/zipstream-php (3.1.0)
 - Locking markbaker/complex (3.0.2)
 - Locking markbaker/matrix (3.0.1)
 - Locking phpoffice/phpspreadsheet (1.29.0)
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Package operations: 7 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
 - Downloading markbaker/matrix (3.0.1)
 - Downloading markbaker/complex (3.0.2)
 - Downloading maennchen/zipstream-php (3.1.0)
 - Downloading ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.17.0)
 - Downloading phpoffice/phpspreadsheet (1.29.0)
- Downloading composer/semver (3.4.0)
- Downloading maatwebsite/excel (3.1.51)
0/7 [>---------------------------]   0%
1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14%
2/7 [========>-------------------]  28%
4/7 [================>-----------]  57%
6/7 [========================>---]  85%
7/7 [============================] 100%
- Installing markbaker/matrix (3.0.1): Extracting archive
- Installing markbaker/complex (3.0.2): Extracting archive
- Installing maennchen/zipstream-php (3.1.0): Extracting archive
- Installing ezyang/htmlpurifier (v4.17.0): Extracting archive
Install of ezyang/htmlpurifier failed
- Installing phpoffice/phpspreadsheet (1.29.0): Extracting archive
 Install of phpoffice/phpspreadsheet failed
- Installing composer/semver (3.4.0): Extracting archive
- Installing maatwebsite/excel (3.1.51): Extracting archive
  Install of maatwebsite/excel failed
 0 [>---------------------------]    0 [->--------------------------]
 In Filesystem.php line 284:

 Could not delete C:\Users\return\Desktop\task_project_crud/vendor/composer/389c7ae0\ezyang-    htmlpurifier-b
bc513d\library\HTMLPurifier\EntityLookup:
This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed


require [--dev] [--dry-run] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--fixed] [--no-suggest] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--update-no-dev] [-w|--update-with-dependencies] [-W|--update-with-all-dependencies] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--apcu-autoloader-prefix APCU-AUTOLOADER-PREFIX] [--] [<packages>...]
```

How to avoid this error....

Comment: Try running the Composer command prompt as an administrator

Comment: Welcome to SO ... it is telling you some possible reasons

Comment: Well, have you tried looking at `This can be due to an antivirus or the Windows Search Indexer locking the file while they are analyzed` ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `maatwebsite/excel` version compatible your php or laravel version if its compatible try this:

```
composer clear-cache
composer update
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
composer require maatwebsite/excel
```

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates that Composer is unable to delete a directory `(HTMLPurifier\EntityLookup)` during the installation process.

**Solution 1:** If you have an antivirus program running, temporarily disable it and then run the composer require maatwebsite/excel command again. Antivirus programs can sometimes lock files and prevent them from being deleted during the installation process.

**Solution 2:** Open a command prompt as an administrator and then run the composer require maatwebsite/excel command. Running Composer with elevated privileges might help overcome permission issues.

**Solution 3:** You can try manually deleting the problematic directory mentioned in the error message `(C:\Users\return\Desktop\task_project_crud/vendor/composer/389c7ae0\ezyang-htmlpurifier-bbc513d\library\HTMLPurifier\EntityLookup)`. After that, run the `composer require maatwebsite/excel` command again.

Comment: But It just showing for few project... For a new project i can run the package...Even while using image intervation package found the same problem in another project..I dont have any antivirus in my pc... If I manually delete those folder,it continually asking to delet a lot of folder.. then the Project does not run..showing a lots of error while running